# Local Convexity and norms

Tags: functional-analysis

Any help with this doubt is appreciated.

I would like to understand the relation between local convexity and norms. I know that all norms are locally convex. But let us say for example I want to prove there is no norm on $L_p(0,1)$ for $0<p<1$, how do I prove this using a characterization of local convexity? What is the characterization of local convexity that can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a metric on $L_p$, namely $d(f,g)=\int |f-g|^p$. It induces a topology. The goal is to show this topology does not come from a norm.

Key idea: if the topology indeed came from a norm $\|\cdot\|$, then the set $B=\{x:\|x\|<1\}$ would have the following property: for any open set $U$ containing $0$ there is $\lambda>0$ such that $\lambda B\subset U$. Any such set $B$ is called *bounded*, which may sound a little strange since boundedness is defined without using a metric. But this notion of boundedness agrees with the standard one when the space has a norm.

A locally convex space is normable if and only if it has a bounded open convex set containing $0$. Indeed, if it is normable, then  $\{x:\|x\|<1\}$ is such a set. Conversely, if we have such as set, then its Minkowski gauge is a norm.

One can show that $L^p$ for $0<p<1$ does not have any nonempty bounded open convex sets. (Hint: prove that every nonempty open convex set is the entire space.)

Comment: Can you elaborate on this statement: for any open set $U$ containing $0$ there is $\lambda > 0$ such that $\lambda B \subset U$

Comment: @pondy Assuming the space has a norm, we know that for every open set containing $0$, there exists $\lambda>0$ such that $\{x:\|x\|<\lambda\}\subset U$. This is just the definition of an open set in a normed space. The set $\{x:\|x\|<\lambda\}$ can be written as $\lambda B$, meaning that it consists of all $\lambda x$ such that $x\in B$.

Comment: If every non empty open convex set is the entire space - how does this imply there are no bounded open convex sets.

Comment: @pondy I omitted "nonempty" in "does not have any nonempty bounded open convex sets"...  Consider the possibility that the entire space satisfies the definition of "bounded" - you will get a contradiction pretty quickly.

Comment: I am still not able to prove that every nonempty open convex set is the entire space. Sorry, I have been trying to do this for so long but without luck.

Comment: @pondy Suppose $U$ contains $0$, is open and convex. Since it's open in the topology of the metric $\int |f-g|^p$, there is $r>0$ such that $\{f: \int |f|^p<r \}\subset U$. The key step is to show that every function $f\in L^p$ can be written as a convex combination of functions $f_j$ with $\int |f_j|^p<r$. By convexity this will imply $f\in U$. The functions $f_j$ come from restricting $f$ to small subintervals (and scaling the restriction appropriately).

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I did check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266892/local-convexity-of-l-p-spaces In that reply of yours, $\int_{J_k} |f|^p=n^{-1}\int_{J_k}|f|^p$ does not make sense to me.

Comment: @pondy I fixed the typo there.